# Amazon S3 files access from multiple processes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

How does AWS handle multiple different threads accessing the same file at the same time? For example, say I have several big (1GB+) data files stored in S3 and two different processes need to work with the file at the same time (for example, one might be copying the data to another bucket while the other process is loading the data into Redshift for analysis). I know for redundancy they keep multiple copies of every file in S3 but how does it handle multiple requests coming in for operations on the same file?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can read the file from as many simultaneous processes as you like. S3 is transactional, so if you try to write from more than one process, the first write will complete, then the next process will overwrite the previous. Therefore be careful when writing from multiple processes.